# prevent stage from receiving mouse events which occur on other objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Despite reading many articles on AS3  and actually completing real world projects, I am still often baffled by simple event handling tasks.

In a current Flex project, the user is able to create instances of a custom BorderContainer-based class, then select and move or resize them. I would like to add an event listener to detect mouse clicks which occur on a background BorderContainer (or the stage) in order to deselect any currently selected instance.

Can someone outline the steps to accomplish this? I've tried everything I can think of (enabling/disabling `useCapture`, trying to compare event.target with event.currentTarget, trying to test eventPhase).

My project is too complicated to post but with the simple test case below, I get the following output and it makes no sense whatsoever to me: the result is the same.

So my question: How do I detect mouse events occurring ONLY on particular objects?

Clicking on an instance of a custom BorderContainer:

```
----------stage click 1
stage is TARGET 1
----------stage click 1
stage is TARGET 1
-----------background click 1
background is currentTarget 1
-----------background click 3
background is currentTarget 3
----------stage click 3
stage is TARGET 3
----------stage click 3
stage is TARGET 3
```

Clicking on the `background` directly:

```
----------stage click 1
stage is TARGET 1
----------stage click 1
stage is TARGET 1
-----------background click 1
background is currentTarget 1
-----------background click 3
background is currentTarget 3
----------stage click 3
stage is TARGET 3
----------stage click 3
stage is TARGET 3
```

//-------------------

```
background.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backgroundClick); 
background.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backgroundClick, true); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stageClick); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stageClick, true);

protected function backgroundClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("-----------background click", event.eventPhase);  

    if (event.target == background){
        trace("background is TARGET",event.eventPhase);
    }

    if (event.currentTarget == background){
        trace("background is currentTarget",event.eventPhase);
    }
} 

protected function stageClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("----------stage click",event.eventPhase); 
    if (event.target == stage){
        trace("stage is currentTarget",event.eventPhase);
    }

    if (event.currentTarget == stage){
        trace("stage is TARGET",event.eventPhase);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click events bubble; that means unless you stop propagation; every component in the hierarchy, from the point where the event was dispatched all the way up to the stage, will receive the click event during the bubble phase.  Adding event listeners on the stage will pick up every click event in the app; as the stage is the top level of the hierarchy.

Normally you would add event listeners to a specific instance of your BorderContainer; not on the stage.

More info on how events work with in the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_05.html).